# wpf move multiple windows together

Tags: c#

i am trying to move 4 windows together at once
i tried some codes but without success

```
private Window1 x = new Window1();
private Window2 z = new Window2();

private void MainWindow_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
    z.Top = this.Left + this.Height;
}
```

and tried

private void MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();

```
x.DragMove();
z.DragMove();
```

}

Comment: Most likely you are using the wrong **reference** to your other windows.  Show us the code where you are displaying those other windows.